# Replot matlab contour plots using gnuplot

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot, file-format, contour

He guys!

I am (slowly) moving away from matlab towards the OS realm and I have recently discovered gnuplot which creates really nice plots so far.

Now I want to replot some graphs I made with matlab earlier this year (contour plots), but I am a bit struggling with the data format for gnuplot.

gnuplot expects the data to be in

```
x0 y0 f(x0, y0)
```

format, whereas for my purpose I created all data files with

```
f(x0,y0), f(x0,y1), f(x0, y2)....
f(x1, y0), ....
..
.
```

format (x and y vectors are always the same so I didnt lose any information). Can I avoid reformatting all my datafiles (which are quite large and many) and still use gnuplot to use the existing files in a 'matlab-like' manner, i.e. contour(z) where z is the data mentioned above?

Thanks for all the support here!

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for `splot '' matrix`, from `help splot matrix`:

```
Example commands for plotting uniform matrix data:
     splot 'file' matrix using 1:2:3          # ascii input
     splot 'file' binary general using 1:2:3  # binary input

In a uniform grid matrix the z-values are read in a row at a time, i. e.,
    z11 z12 z13 z14 ...
    z21 z22 z23 z24 ...
    z31 z32 z33 z34 ...
and so forth.
```